# Visual Studio 2017 - Can't turn off "Live Testing"

Tags: visual-studio, tdd

Help - I made the mistake of turning on live testing, and now I can't turn it off or disable it.

Specs
Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.7
NUnit v3.9.0
NUnit3TestAdapter v3.9.0

Symptoms.
Once I do a "Test | Run | All Tests" I can no longer run my tests.  I'm assuming that it's because "they're already running."

This is frustrating because I have 4 integration tests that I have "Ignored" out, but once I have run all tests one time, I can't just comment out the Ignore line and run the test on its own.
By commenting it out and hitting F6 to rebuild, it will run ALL of my tests again.

Nice feature, but I don't like it.  I want to turn it off.
In theory I should be able to turn it off by clicking
"Test | Live Testing | Stop"
but that doesn't change the behavior much.
The difference between Start and Stop is the following:
Start - I comment or uncomment the ignore and the tests runs immediately.
Stop - I comment or uncomment the ignore and the tests run when I build.

Apparently I'm the only one having issues, because searching for:
Visual Studio Disable "Live Testing"
gets me a whole lot of response on how to turn it on and make it work and nothing on how to disable it.

Comment: Edit: I just noticed that in the test explorer window, there is a "Cancel" link.  If I click that, it gets replaced by a "Run All" link.  
This solves 95% of my problem, but I'd still like a way to turn the live testing functionality off-off, or better yet, uninstall it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is in your original post.

In the Visual Studio 2017 menu bar, go **Test** >> **Live Unit Testing** >> **Stop**

If this doesn't work for you, perhaps try checking for Visual Studio Updates. I'm on 15.6.7 and doing this does indeed turn off Live Unit Testing.

Comment: But how do you make it not start